# Disabled Select drop down checking through PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a couple of drop down boxes I access through POST with PHP.  When the boxes are disabled and not equal to zero I have the program do something.  However when they are disabled I do not want them to do anything.  The way I check if the boxes are active is by using an if statement

```
if ($_POST['box'] != "blank"){

//do something

}
```

So basically I check if the box is not in the default blank position run the if statement.

However when it is disabled I am not sure how to check or what kind of value it returns if any.  What can I add to the if statement so it will not go into the loop when the boxes are disabled?

I tried:

```
   if ($_POST['box'] != "blank" || $_POST['box'] != ""){

    //do something

    }
```

But that did not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that a form is just something that sends an HTTP POST request to a web server. From PHP's point of view, it has no idea that someone clicked submit on a form, it just sees some POST data that could have came from anywhere.

That said, a disabled form element will not be submitted. Instead, try something like

```
if (!isset($_POST['box'])) {
    //box was not submitted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When HTML elements are disabled, they do not create an entry within the $_POST variable.

So if you're positive that the POST submission coming in contains a the 'box' field, then you can go:

```
if (!isset($_POST['box']) || $_POST['box'] != "blank") {
  echo "The box field is disabled or blank";
}
```

Now, your code wasn't working because `$_POST['box'] != ""` checks if `$_POST['box']` is not an empty string. Having any content will then make your if conditional true.